# OnetoMany not populating with parent id in child object

Tags: java, jpa, liquibase

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_EMPLOYEE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Employee implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "creator")
    private String creator;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Car> cars;


    public List<Car> getCars() {
        return columnboards;
    }

    public void setCars(List<Car> cars) {
        this.cars = cars;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;

    }

    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "T_CAR")
public class Car implements Serializable {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "car_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "car_name")
    private String carName;



    @ManyToOne
    private Employee car;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy="car", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Collection<Driver> drivers;

    public String getCarName() {
        return carName;
    }

    public void setCarName(String carName) {
        this.carName = carName;
    }

    public Collection<Driver> getDrivers() {
        return drivers;
    }

    public void setCards(Collection<Driver> drivers) {
        this.drivers = drivers;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "T_DRIVER")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Driver implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "driver_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "point")
    private String point;

    @Column(name = "colour")
    private String colour;

    @ManyToOne
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Car car;

    public String getPoint() {
        return point;
    }

    public void setPoint(String point) {
        this.point = point;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public void setColour(String colour) {
        this.colour = colour;
    }
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


}
```

I have the three entities above and the tables are created using Liquibase

```
<createTable tableName="T_EMPLOYEE">
    <column name="employee_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="name" type="varchar(255)" />
    <column name="creator" type="varchar(255)" />
</createTable>





<createTable tableName="T_COLUMN_BOARD">
    <column name="CAR_ID" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="car_name" type="varchar(255)" />
    <column name="employee_employee_id" type="bigint" />
</createTable>


<createTable tableName="T_DRIVER">
    <column name="driver_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="true">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
    </column>
    <column name="point" type="varchar(255)" />
    <column name="colour" type="varchar(255)" />
    <column name="CAR_ID_FK" type="bigint" />
</createTable>


<addForeignKeyConstraint
    baseColumnNames="employee_employee_id"
    baseTableName="T_CAR"
        constraintName="fk_car_employee_id"
    referencedColumnNames="employee_id"
    referencedTableName="T_EMPLOYEE" />

<addForeignKeyConstraint
    baseColumnNames="CAR_ID_FK"
    baseTableName="T_DRIVER"
    constraintName="fk_driver_car_id"
    referencedColumnNames="CAR_ID"
    referencedTableName="T_CAR" />
```

The issue I am having is that whenever I try to save the entity with a list of Cars and a list of Drivers. I see the following in the database:

```
T_EMPLOYEE 
EMPLOYEE_ID     NAME        CREATOR  
1             John          john@example.com



T_CAR
CAR_ID      CAR_NAME    employee_employee_id  
1           ford            null
2           Honda           null
3           Audi            null
4           Opel            null
```

I would have expected to see the the Employee_ID in the T_CAR.employee_employee_id column. So something like this.

```
T_CAR
CAR_ID      CAR_NAME    employee_employee_id  
1           ford            1
2           Honda           1
3           Audi            1
4           Opel            1
```

I have been racking my head all day on this or have I completely missed something.

The rest service, send down a json object to the service.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeResource.class);

    @Inject
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/Employees",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> create(@RequestBody Employee employee) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Employee : {}", employee);
        if (employee.getId() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().header("Failure", "A new employee cannot already have an ID").build();
        }
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/employees/" + employee.getId())).build();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees",
        method = RequestMethod.PUT,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Void> update(@RequestBody Employee employee) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Employee : {}", employee);
        if (employee.getId() == null) {
            return create(employee);
        }
        employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAll(@RequestParam(value = "page" , required = false) Integer offset,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "per_page", required = false) Integer limit)
        throws URISyntaxException {
        Page<Employee> page = employeeRepository.findAll(PaginationUtil.generatePageRequest(offset, limit));
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/employees", offset, limit);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Employee get(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Employee : {}", id);
        return employeeRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.DELETE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Employee : {}", id);
        employeeRepository.delete(id);
    }
}





public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Long> {

}
```

Comment: Please also post the code persisting those entities

Comment: Sorry about the delay in updating that.

Comment: You don't have any code persisting drivers.